# How to import java classes between Maven Projects in netbeans

Tags: java, class, maven, netbeans, project

I know from previous stackoverflow questions that IT IS possible to import java classes between projects in Netbeans, but is it possible to do between 2 Maven projects? (when you right click on a Maven project the options do no show any import libraries)

Comment: Right click on dependencies, add dependency. look for group id and artifact id. if it's you project thats the dependency, make sure its in your local repo

Comment: Those are 2 projects I cloned from git, and now I manipulate them

Comment: I believe when you build a maven project in netbeans it automatically installs to the local repo. You should be able to right click on the dependencies node in the project explorer and select add dependency. Then type the group and artifact id and it should come up. Have you tried?

Comment: Or better yet, forget the groupid and artifactid. Just type in the artifact id into the "query" field, and it'll search your local repo

Comment: Or wait, you can actually just add any open project as a dependency. In the dialog of the "add dependency", just select a project from the "open projects" tab

Comment: Tried your last suggestion, but now have maven not compiling:  `Failed to execute goal com.theoryinpractise:clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.12:compile (compile) on project storm-starter: Clojure failed. -> [Help 1]`